# Lotus Notes Swing PDF Converter Error

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Can anyone explain to me what this error really means?

*"Exception number 19000: Exception number 4000: Notes error: Field is too large (32K) or View's column & selection formulas are too large (code 6)
at swing.pdfconverter.SwPDFMain.RAISEERROR (SwPDFMain.ls:152)"*

This error occurs **sometimes** when I try to convert a PDF document from Lotus Notes 8.5 with SWING PDF Converter 6.10.
This error occurs in the function SwUtilsLib.SwGenerateUniqueFileName().

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic Lotus Notes error message that occurs when data for a document exceeds the summary buffer limit. Without knowing what Swing's converter is doing under the covers, it's impossible to say exactly which document and which field(s) are causing the problem. I think this is something you need to contact Swing about.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tip. I contacted them and it's ok now.